# JavaScript conditionals if parallel?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

So I try to find some command as next? or something,

In order to do one if statement and then another, in result both if statements will be executed.

Logic:

```
for(loop)
if ( sth == 1) {
TODO
}

next() //It is possible to do two if parallel??

if ( sth == 2) {
TODO
}
```

After this two statements i push to variables.length to newArray

The Problem is i cannot use operators as && or || because the data set wchich will be filtered can change a lot, so it can have sth == 1 or not, so i want that my loop search precisely   for the first if statement and if there is nothing it is 0 or some other value which will be add to array and the same with second statement. It can happen that one or two if statement will give 0 results or just one 0 and some other value. I hope i expressed myself well enough to understand my issue

Comment: You check for the second only if the first is triggered?

Comment: You should use Promises - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple...

```
var j=0;

function check()
{
j++;
if(j==2) next();
}

if ( sth == 1) {
check();
}

if ( sth == 2) {
check();
}
```